# How do I set content in my pages so that it remains permanent while blog posts are added below?

Tags: posts, customization, pages, page-template, content

Is there a way to post content that does not move or remains "static" within different pages? I am trying to set a description of each of my pages on my blog to give the reader an intro about each page. Is this Possible?

Example:

This is how I would want my "Audio Stories" page to look....

(Page)Audio Stories
(Content) In this section you will find tales of random encounters with strangers from around the world.

blog post

blog post

blog post

etc..

Comment: Is Audio Stories as post category? Or is a page under "Pages"?

Comment: More detail needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show that static content in your post then you can find post.php template in your theme and find function "the_content();" just before this function make a div for your static content and add our static content there.
Similarly if you want to show that content in page then find page.php template which is default and archive.php for category page.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the [category (taxonomy term)](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/term_description) description and print the description in your archive page.